# Significato di "sgattare"

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Il contesto*, di Leonardo Sciascia, ho letto:

> Sotto al libro c'era uno di quei cartoncini promemoria che trovano nelle sigarette di lusso: e l'ispettore pensò che Cres lo aveva usato come segnalibro, e se non stava in mezzo al libro si poteva presumere che avesse finito di leggerlo.  "Su via, ora finiamola coi discorsi e andiamo al pranzo funebre. Non turbatevi per il fatto che mangeremo le frittelle. È una vecchia, antica usanza, e anch'essa ha del buono". Forse lo aveva finito aspettando che si facesse l'ora di **sgattare**, dopo aver sistemato ogni cosa nella previsione dell'irruzione poliziesca in sua assenza.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa "sgattare"? Non ho trovato questo verbo in nessun dizionario.

Comment: Potrebbe essere una variante di sgattaiolare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sgattare sembra essere una variante di [sgattaiolare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sgattaiolare/):

> **sgattaiolare** v. intr. [der. di gattaiola, col pref. s- (nel sign. 3)]
>   (io sgattàiolo, o sgattaiòlo, ecc.; aus. essere). – Con riferimento a
>   gatti, entrare, uscire con agilità e sveltezza attraverso la
>   gattaiola. **Con uso estens. e fig., riferito ad altri animali e a
>   persone, entrare, uscire quatto quatto, in silenzio e con sveltezza,
>   cercando di passare inosservato**: *la lepre sgattaiolò via tra i
>   cespugli; il ladro riuscì a s. dentro un portone e a sfuggire agli
>   inseguitori; alcuni fra gli uditori sgattaiolarono dal recinto,
>   corsero a sussurrare le notizie nel quartiere* (Fogazzaro). Con la
>   particella pron. e la indeterminato, sottrarsi a un danno, a un
>   pericolo, a qualcosa di spiacevole: *spero di riuscire a
>   sgattaiolarmela anche questa volta.*

Come giustamente segnalato da @Charo viene utilizzato con significato simile anche ne [Il sovversivo di Adamo Calabrese, 2012](https://www.vorrei.org/rubriche/la-valigia-dei-libri/4591-il-sovversivo.html):

> Tutti hanno sentito Radio Londra: “Ocio, ocio!!! Tocca a voi: Le viole
>   sono fiorite!” Cioè: “Arriva uno squadrone di fortezze volanti in
>   picchiata sullo stabilimento. ” Il mio signor padre ***sgatta*** fuori
>   dalla Magneti Marelli (fabbrica di girabecchini per autoblindo)
>   confuso nel formicaio dei tornitori attrezzisti che fugge dai reparti
>   bellici. Salta sulla bicicletta, salta per modo di dire, più giusto
>   spiegare che s’arrampica sulla due ruote, inaccessibile “Pizzo dei tre
>   signori” tanto è più alta dell’uno e cinquanta del ciclista. È su, in
>   vetta, se pure artrofico, mentre tentacola col piede destro il pedale
>   che sfugge e col sinistro punta il suolo. Bombardano! Lui arranca di
>   sghimbescio come se avesse il colpo della strega. Bum, bum, bum…
>   “Hanno colpito il laminatoio! Anche la mensa! Patate dappertutto! L’ho
>   visto io!”

E nella legenda dello stesso brano si può leggere:

> “Sgatta.” Contrazione di sgattaiolare

Comment: Sembra che se ne parli anche [qui](https://www.vorrei.org/rubriche/la-valigia-dei-libri/4591-il-sovversivo.html).

Comment: La cosa interessante è che, alla fine di questo racconto di Adamo Calabrese si spiega: “Sgatta.” Contrazione di sgattaiolare.